# My app not appear on AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to create a new Android project and run it it did not appear on the emulator.

This is the console message :

```
[2014-04-12 00:30:57 - Fir] Android Launch!
[2014-04-12 00:30:57 - Fir] adb is running normally.
[2014-04-12 00:30:57 - Fir] Performing com.example.fir.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-04-12 00:31:05 - Fir] Uploading Fir.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-12 00:31:06 - Fir] Installing Fir.apk...
[2014-04-12 00:31:22 - Fir] Success!
[2014-04-12 00:31:22 - Fir] Starting activity com.example.fir.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

I wait more than one hour and its not appear? And I try to kill-server adb and start it again, but still the same problem.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try the genymotion Emulator. It is faster than the normal android Emulator.

Can you post your manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This is my manifest.xml ,And i will try the genymotion Emulator

```
  `  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.fir"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fir.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     </application>

     </manifest>`
```